# Recommendations for study material on Magento designing

Tags: magento-1.7, template, layout

I am very new to Magento but with help of some sites 
I have installed magento 1.7 and it's working fine.

Now I would like to change the design of the homepage and I could really use some tutorials on how to do that.

Can anyone suggest some sites of tutorials that might help me?

Comment: am asking where i change coding in this magento i mean which folders

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an in-depth look: many people are enthousiastic about Alan Storm's [No Frills Magento Layout](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout). It goes into all the details of Magento layouts. If you're serious about Magento layout and development, I'd highly recommend it. It does require you to work with HTML, CSS and PHP. Working with Magento layouts there's no escaping this, unless you're happy with a pre-made theme or skin.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an extensive subject. Your homepage is a CMS page with both a `content` section with a WYSIWYG editor and a custom XML layout section. Using the layout section will allow you to make the most changes.

The following links will learn you more about Widgets and the way Magento Layout works

1. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento
2. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package
3. http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/introducing-magento-widgets/
4. http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_widgets.htm
5. Online course: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/
6. PDF's on designing: http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/magento-user-guide
7. http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes
8. Magento U trainings: http://www.magentocommerce.com/services/training
9. Excellent tutsplus article: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ecommerce/magento-project-guidelines-for-designers/

Depending on how much you want to change you'll have quite a long read laying ahead. Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome. You've might have noticed general questions like these normally don't go well on the forum. I suggest reading up and posting specific questions if you have any :)

Comment: @Thulasiram and don't forget to close this ticket either by voting or deleting it.